# Upload File in Object

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

What am I doing wrong?

**fileUpload.cfm**

```
<cfcomponent name="fileAttachment" hint="This is the File Attachment Object">

    <cffunction name="uploadFile" access="public" output="no" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="fileToUpload" type="string" required="no">
        <cfargument name="pDsn" required="no" type="string">
        <cfset var cffile = "">
        <cffile action="upload" destination="D:\apache\htdocs\abc\uploads" filefield="#ARGUMENTS.fileToUpload#" nameconflict="makeunique">
        <cfreturn cffile.clientFile />
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

**test_fileUpload.cfm**

```
<form action="fileUpload.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
<cffile action="upload" destination="D:\apache\htdocs\abc\uploads" filefield="#ARGUMENTS.fileToUpload#" nameconflict="makeunique">
```

The filefield attribute wants the *name of the form field* that will hold the uploaded file. You're on the right track, but unfortunately, that's not what the value of `#ARGUMENTS.fileToUpload#` is, presently--based on your construction, it holds a reference to the actual file itself.

Add a new hidden field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nameOfField" value="fileToUpload">
```

Then, pass `FORM.nameOfField` to your uploadFile() method as the first parameter. CFFILE will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found lots of issue with this code.

1. fileupload.cfm should be component file fileupload.**cfc** as you are writing component in it.
2. As you are going to call directly upload method from form call access type must be **REMOTE**.
3. action page should change to fileupload.cfc?method=uploadFile
4. if you define cffile as local variable of component then you have to specify result="cffile" attribute in cffile tag.
5. filefield attribute take the name of form field not its value so just remove ## tag and just use fileToUpload.

Below is correct code.
**fileupload.cfc**

```
<cffunction name="uploadFile" access="remote" output="no" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="fileToUpload" type="string" required="no">
    <cfargument name="pDsn" required="no" type="string">
    <cfset var cffile = "">
    <cffile action="upload" destination="D:\apache\htdocs\abc\uploads" filefield="fileToUpload" result="cffile" nameconflict="makeunique">
    <cfreturn cffile.clientFile />
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

**test_fileupload.cfm**

```
<form action="fileupload.cfc?method=uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload"><br/>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```