# Receiving an uploaded file in a Coldfusion CFC

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, coldfusion

I have a Backbone front-end that is sending restful calls with an uploaded file to a Coldfusion backend.

I need to know how to 'get at' the file once it has reached my CFC. Unfortunately i have some doubt as to whether the file is being sent at all, my POST goes off fine and returns a basic string from the CFC so i know that is working.

The POST payload looks like this

```
------WebKitFormBoundarymjCH1xJJ2D10ncj8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="Jellyfish.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarymjCH1xJJ2D10ncj8--
```

I am using jquery FineUploader to send the request.

I am currently using this to try and pick up the file on the CFC end.

```
<cfcomponent displayname="import"
             rest="true" 
             restPath="/import">

    <cffunction name="import" 
                access="remote" 
                httpMethod="POST"
                produces="application/json"
                returntype="string">

        <cfset local.testResponse= "Response">
        <cfset local.testDebug= "Test Debug">
        <cfif IsDefined("Form.UploadFile") AND Form.UploadFile NEQ "">
            <cfsavecontent variable="local.debugInfo">
                <cfdump var="#local.testDebug#">
            </cfsavecontent>
            <cffile action="write" file="c:\Coldfusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\backend\debugInfo.html" output="#local.debugInfo#">
        </cfif>

        <!--- GET THE FILE SENT WITH THE AJAX CALL AND DO SOMETHING --->

        <!--- Here we should return some JSON that has a success value? --->
        <cfreturn local.testResponse>

    </cffunction> 


</cfcomponent>
```

I think there is probably some concept i am missing here so im unsure of how to really word this question. Apologies...

Comment: look at cffile tag upload action. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733270/upload-file-in-object?rq=1

Comment: I've followed this through as far as i can but im getting 'The form field formTest did not contain a file.' Im not actually ever submitting a form i dont think as i am using the jquery uploader so that is probably the issue. Surely its not necessary for me to have to send a form though or is that just the way coldfusion has to handle being sent a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was knowledge problem rather than any real technical difficulty. My file was getting sent properly, to 'pick up' a file on the Coldfusion end of the request I used this.

```
<cffile 
    action = "upload"
    destination = "C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\tempFiles\"
    accept = "image/jpeg, application/xlsx"
    nameConflict = "overwrite"
    result="myFile"
>
```

Thanks to sunny for the pointers

Comment: I'd suggest not uploading files into a web-accessible location like that. It's a security risk.  A best practice approach is to upload to a folder completely outside the web root first, validate the uploaded file is not malicious, then move into a web-accessible location *if necessary*.