# What should restArgSource value be for Coldfusion 10 Rest Services and enctype?

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, enctype

Here is a simple example of adding enctype attribute to a form tag and watching the passed parameters become missing.

```
## test.rest.cfm
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>Will Post From Here</p>
<form method="post" action="http://devserver/rest/ost/testform/" name="frmName">
<table>
<tr>
<td>fname</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="Fredley"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>lname</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname" value="Solongo"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Post"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

## testFormHandler.cfc
<cfcomponent restpath="testform" rest="true" produces="application/JSON">

<cffunction description="POST method to test form"
name         = "postMethod"
access       = "remote"
output       = "false"
returntype   = "string"
returnformat = "json"
httpmethod   = "post" >

<cfargument required="1" type="any" restArgSource="Form" name="fname">
<cfargument required="1" type="any" restArgSource="Form" name="lname">

<cfset var arrayReturn = {}>
<cfset arrayReturn["fname"] = arguments.fname>
<cfset arrayReturn["lname"] = arguments.lname>

<cfreturn "{""PayLoad"":" & SerializeJSON(arrayReturn) & ",""Type"":""Success"",""Message"":""SUCCESS"",""Code"":""SUCCESS""}">

</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>

## change form tag of test.rest.cfm to gets param fname failure
<form method="post" action="http://dev1.ostit.com/rest/ost/testform/" name="frmName" enctype="multipart/form-data">

## results with no enctype
{"PayLoad":{"fname":"Fredley","lname":"Solongo"},"Type":"Success","Message":"SUCCESS","Code":"SUCCESS"}

## results with enctype added
{"Message":"The FNAME parameter to the postMethod function is required but was not passed in."}
```

Should the restArgSource be different when the enctype is included?  Obviously, the http headers change, but using header with a restargname didn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [getting started guide](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html) says this:

"Also, you must set the content-type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded when sending data as form fields."

So you may be out of luck I'm afraid. You may be able to get a handle to the underlying http request and access the request body like that, but it'd be a fair amount of work. What's the reasoning behind using multipart forms? I'd guess at file upload, but I'd be interested to know whether there's another use case.

It looks like [file upload itself will work in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678956/receiving-an-uploaded-file-in-a-coldfusion-cfc) using regular CFFile handling. If you can handle placing other parameters on the URL, you may get something workable.